# Keep formatting of text when pasting text from Google Docs to MailChimp

Tags: google-drive

Is there a way of keeping the formatting of text when pasting text from Google Docs to MailChimp?

This is just for bold and italic formatting.

Answer (score 2):

This is not actually true, when you copy from Google there are 3 data types:

`text/plain` - the one without formatting

`text/html` - the one with formatting

`application/x-vnd.google-docs-document-slice-clip+wrapped` - a crazy Google JSON formatted one which is huge and virtually indecipherable probably used internally for copying between google docs

I haven't looked at MailChimp but the probable reason is that google docs does not maintain a nice html semantic format.

If you write an unformatted line in the doc you might expect it to look like:

```
<p>A nice paragraph</p>
```

But in reality the html clipboard looks more like:

```
<meta charset='utf-8'><meta charset="utf-8"><b style="font-weight:normal;" id="docs-internal-guid-5b7b4b50-04f3-9f84-1b27-7991efe9c66f"><span style="font-size:14.666666666666666px;font-family:Arial;color:#000000;background-color:transparent;font-weight:400;font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;text-decoration:none;vertical-align:baseline;white-space:pre-wrap;">A nice paragraph</span></b>
```

So it's understandable that companies will either give you the plain-text version or strip out this hideous mess and give you a very filtered-down version so that styling isn't broken on their site.

What Google should be doing is providing semantic html in another stream, as I am guessing the `text/html` one is used by Word for example to display the content exactly as you saw it.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to say so, but when copying text around from one program to another, only the text is getting copied and not the formatting.

Only the text you copy gets saved in the clipboard and not the formatting. Keeping the formatting is only possible if you copy from MS-Office to MS-office, Google Docs to Google Docs etc... but not across different services.